# Remote activate android app

Tags: remote-control, ouya

I have an OUYA with XBMC installed, and watch films using the remote app on my Android phone. To watch a film I have to use the Ouya controller to launch XBMC. How can I remotely start XBMC on my android device (the OUYA) so not needing the controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look in the [OUYA store](https://www.ouya.tv/games/) for an app called [AutoPilot](https://www.ouya.tv/game/AutoPilot/), that allows you to specify an app that will run on boot.